# How to use proxie to open 'https' website by urllib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler, urllib

```
proxy_support=urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http':random.choice(iplist)})
opener=urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
```

But if i use it to open a 'https' website, it does not use proxies.How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
proxy_support=urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http':random.choice(iplist)})
```

You only provided proxy for `http`.
For sites with `https` you need separate proxy.

```
urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http':random.choice(iplist), 'https': "https://host:port'})
```